# Conjunctive Normal Form Conversion

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The question is to turn the following formula into Conjunctive Normal Form:

> $\rm \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (r \to s)] \to p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s$

I have come up to here:

> $\rm \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (r \to s)] \to (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s) 
> \\[2ex]
> \rm \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \to (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s) 
> \\[2ex]
> \rm \neg \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \vee [p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s] 
> \\[2ex]
> \rm [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \vee [p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s]
> \\[2ex]
> \rm [(p \vee q) \vee (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)] \wedge [(\neg r \vee s) \vee (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)] $

From here forward, I have no clue what the next step could be. Any hints or guidance would be very useful. Thanks

EDIT: I've worked further ahead, but I am not sure if this would be correct as I have a gut feeling that I made an error in some of the steps

> $\rm \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (r \to s)] \to (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)
> \\[2ex]
> \rm \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \to (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)
> \\[2ex]
> \rm \neg \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \vee [p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s]
> \\[2ex]
> \rm [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \vee [p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s]
> \\[2ex]
> \rm [(p \vee q) \vee (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)] \wedge [(\neg r \vee s) \vee (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)]
> \\[2ex]
> \rm [[(p \wedge p) \vee (p \wedge q)] \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s] \wedge [(\neg s \wedge s) \vee (\neg s \wedge \neg r)] \wedge p \wedge \neg q]
> \\[2ex]
> \rm [[p \vee (p \wedge q)] \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s] \wedge [(\neg s \wedge \neg r) \wedge p \wedge \neg q]
> \\[2ex]
> \rm p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s \wedge \neg s \wedge \neg r \wedge p \wedge \neg q
> \\[2ex]
> \rm p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s \wedge \neg r \wedge p \wedge \neg q
> \\[2ex]
> \rm p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s \wedge \neg r$

Comment: Relabel $p\lor q$ as $t_1$ and $\neg r\lor s$ as $t_2$, then distribute what it's inside each [ ] and go from there.

Comment: I don't understand what I could use to distribute past
[(t1) v (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬s)] ∧ [(t2) v (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬s)]

Comment: Recall that $A\lor (B\land C)\iff (A\lor B)\land (A\lor C)$.

Comment: I am absolutely clueless on how to use that on what I have at the moment since I have 3 variables in (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬s)

Comment: I have edited the question to show where I am currently standing

Answer (score 1):

Let's see: $\rm \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (r \to s)] \to (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)
\\[2ex] 
\rm \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \to (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)
\\[2ex]
\rm \neg \neg [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \vee [p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s]
\\[2ex]
\rm [(p \vee q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s)] \vee [p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s]
\\[2ex]
\rm [(p \vee q) \vee (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)] \wedge [(\neg r \vee s) \vee (p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s)]
\\[2ex] \text{That's okay up till here, then you went horribly wrong.}
\\[2ex]\require{cancel}
\rm \xcancel{[[(p \wedge p) \vee (p \wedge q)] \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg s] \wedge [(\neg s \wedge s) \vee (\neg s \wedge \neg r)] \wedge p \wedge \neg q]}
\\[2ex]\text{The next few steps should be:}
\\[2ex]
\rm [(p \vee q \vee p) \wedge (p \vee q \vee \neg q) \wedge (p \vee q \vee \neg s)] \wedge [(\neg r \vee s \vee p) \wedge (\neg r \vee s \vee \neg q) \wedge (\neg r \vee s \vee \neg s)]
\\[2ex]
\rm [(p \vee q) \wedge \top \wedge (p \vee q \vee \neg s)] \wedge [(\neg r \vee s \vee p) \wedge (\neg r \vee s \vee \neg q) \wedge \top]
\\[2ex]
\rm (p \vee q) \wedge [(\neg r \vee s) \vee (p \wedge \neg q)]
$

Can you finish from here?